# Where does Flash Player store its trusted site list on Linux?

Tags: security, flash

Specifically, we have a fairly large network of HP thin clients running HP ThinPro (a variant of Debian) with Adobe Flash Player pre-installed.  We have a new application coming to the network which will make use of the camera.  Flash is doing its job and asking for permission to use the camera every time the page loads.  Unfortunately, it is not giving us the options to add the site/domain to its trusted list to not ask for permission every time (perhaps due to the locked file system, not certain why the advanced options aren't coming up).  In any case, we're trying to find where Flash Player stores this information so we can go edit it manually in the file system (we can unlock it temporarily, make the change, and re-lock, then capture the system image for later deployments).  We've not been able to find where it's located.  Any thoughts or ideas where to look?

Answer (score 1):

I checked this out with webcamtoy.com on my Ubuntu workstation using Google Chrome.

The data was recorded here

```
/home/rbabchis/.config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/WritableRoot/#SharedObjects/UL8AK5CB/macromedia.com/support/flashplayer/sys/#webcamtoy.com/settings.sol
```

It contained

```
$ hexdump -C settings.sol 
00000000  00 bf 00 00 00 4d 54 43  53 4f 00 04 00 00 00 00  |.....MTCSO......|
00000010  00 16 77 65 62 63 61 6d  74 6f 79 2e 63 6f 6d 2f  |..webcamtoy.com/|
00000020  73 65 74 74 69 6e 67 73  00 00 00 00 00 05 61 6c  |settings......al|
00000030  6c 6f 77 01 01 00 00 06  61 6c 77 61 79 73 01 00  |low.....always..|
00000040  00 00 06 6b 6c 69 6d 69  74 00 40 59 00 00 00 00  |...klimit.@Y....|
00000050  00 00 00                                          |...|
00000053
```

It also created these files that don't seem to be very useful

```
./.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/https_webcamtoy.com_0.localstorage-journal
./.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/https_webcamtoy.com_0.localstorage
```